# Tkinter While обновление в цикле Label или text поля

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Использую цикл `while` с `tkinter` нужно чтобы или в `Label` или в текстовом поле (неважно) каждую итерацию цикла обновлялся текст:

```
from tkinter import *

def start():
    playerTile, computerTile = enterPlayerTile()

    while True:
        finalBoard = playGame(playerTile, computerTile)

        # Отобразить итоговый счет
        drawBoard(finalBoard)
        scores = getScoreOfBoard(finalBoard)
        print('X набрал %s очков. O набрал %s очков.' % (scores['X'], scores['O']))
        if scores[playerTile] > scores[computerTile]:
            print('Поздравляю! вы победили компьютер обогнав его на %s очков.' % (
                        scores[playerTile] - scores[computerTile]))
        elif scores[playerTile] < scores[computerTile]:
            print('Робот одержал победу. Восстание машин близко. компьютер обогнал вас на %s очков.' % (
                        scores[computerTile] - scores[playerTile]))
        else:
            print('Ничья!')

        print('Хотите сыграть еще раз? (да или нет)')
        if not input().lower().startswith('д'):
            break

# Reversi
import random
import sys
WIDTH = 8
HEIGHT = 8
def drawBoard(board):
    # Вывести игровое поле, переданное этой функции. Ничего не возвращать.
    vivod=""
    vivod+=('   1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  ')+"\n"
    vivod +=(' @ +  +  +  +  +  +  +  + @')+"\n"
    for y in range(HEIGHT):
        vivod +=('%s|' % str(y+1) )
        for x in range(WIDTH):
            vivod +=str(board[x][y])
        vivod +=('|%s' % (y+1))+"\n"
    vivod+=(' @ +  +  +  +  +  +  +  + @')+"\n"
    vivod+=('   1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  ')+"\n"




def getNewBoard():
    # Создать структуру данных нового чистого игрового поля.
    board = []
    for i in range(WIDTH):
        board.append([' - ', ' - ', ' - ', ' - ', ' - ', ' - ', ' - ', ' - '])
    return board

def isValidMove(board, tile, xstart, ystart):
    # Вернуть False, если ход игрока в клетку с координатами xstart, ystart - недопустимый.
    # Если это допустимый ход, вернуть список клеток, которые "присвоил" бы игрок, если бы сделал туда ход.
    if board[xstart][ystart] != ' - ' or not isOnBoard(xstart, ystart):
        return False

    if tile == ' X ':
        otherTile = ' O '
    else:
        otherTile = ' X '

    tilesToFlip = []
    for xdirection, ydirection in [[0, 1], [1, 1], [1, 0], [1, -1], [0, -1], [-1, -1], [-1, 0], [-1, 1]]:
        x, y = xstart, ystart
        x += xdirection # Первый шаг в направлении x
        y += ydirection # Первый шаг в направлении Y
        while isOnBoard(x, y) and board[x][y] == otherTile:
            # Продолжать двигаться в этом направлении x и y
            x += xdirection
            y += ydirection
            if isOnBoard(x, y) and board[x][y] == tile:
                # Есть фишки, которые можно перевернуть. Двигаться в обратном направлении до достижения исходной клетки, отмечая все фишки на этом пути
                while True:
                    x -= xdirection
                    y -= ydirection
                    if x == xstart and y == ystart:
                        break
                    tilesToFlip.append([x, y])

    if len(tilesToFlip) == 0:     # Вернуть True, если координаты есть на игровом поле.
        return False
    return tilesToFlip

def isOnBoard(x, y):
    # Вернуть True, если координаты есть на игровом поле.
    return x >= 0 and x <= WIDTH - 1 and y >= 0 and y <= HEIGHT - 1

def getBoardWithValidMoves(board, tile):
    # Вернуть новое поле с точками, обозначающими допустимые ходы, которые может сделать игрок
    boardCopy = getBoardCopy(board)

    for x, y in getValidMoves(boardCopy, tile):
        boardCopy[x][y] = '[+]'
    return boardCopy

def getValidMoves(board, tile):
    # Вернуть список списков с координатами x и y допустимых ходов для данного игрока на данном игровом поле.
    validMoves = []
    for x in range(WIDTH):
        for y in range(HEIGHT):
            if isValidMove(board, tile, x, y) != False:
                validMoves.append([x, y])
    return validMoves

def getScoreOfBoard(board):
    # Определить количество очков, подсчитав фишки. Вернуть словарь с ключами 'X' и 'O'
    xscore = 0
    oscore = 0
    for x in range(WIDTH):
        for y in range(HEIGHT):
            if board[x][y] == ' X ':
                xscore += 1
            if board[x][y] == ' O ':
                oscore += 1
    return {' X ':xscore, ' O ':oscore}

def enterPlayerTile():
    # Позволить игроку ввести выбранную фишку
    # Возвращает список с фишкой игрока в качестве первого элемента и фишкой компьютера в качестве второго
    tile = ''
    while not (tile == 'X' or tile == 'O'):
        print('Вы играете за X или за O?')
        tile = input().upper()

    # Первый элемент в списке - фишка игрока, второй элемент - фишка компьютера
    if tile == 'X':
        return [' X ', ' O ']
    else:
        return [' O ', ' X ']

def whoGoesFirst():
    # Случайно выбрать, кто ходит первым
    if random.randint(0, 1) == 0:
        return 'компьютер'
    else:
        return 'игрок'

def makeMove(board, tile, xstart, ystart):
    # Поместить фишку на игровое поле в позицию xstart, ystart и перевернуть какую-либо фишку противника
    # Вернуть False, если это недопустимый ход; вернуть True, если допустимый
    tilesToFlip = isValidMove(board, tile, xstart, ystart)

    if tilesToFlip == False:
        return False

    board[xstart][ystart] = tile
    for x, y in tilesToFlip:
        board[x][y] = tile
    return True

def getBoardCopy(board):
    # Сделать копию списка board и вернуть ее
    boardCopy = getNewBoard()

    for x in range(WIDTH):
        for y in range(HEIGHT):
            boardCopy[x][y] = board[x][y]

    return boardCopy

def isOnCorner(x, y):
    # Вернуть True, если указанная позиция находится в одном из четырех углов
    return (x == 0 or x == WIDTH - 1) and (y == 0 or y == HEIGHT - 1)

def getPlayerMove(board, playerTile):
    # Позволить игроку ввести свой ход
    # Вернуть ход в виде [x, y] (или вернуть строки 'подсказка' или 'выход')
    DIGITS1TO8 = '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8'.split()
    while True:
        print('Введите свой ход, "выход" для закрытия игры или "подсказка" для отображения подсказки')
        move = input().lower()
        if move == 'выход' or move == 'подсказка':
            return move

        if len(move) == 2 and move[0] in DIGITS1TO8 and move[1] in DIGITS1TO8:
            x = int(move[0]) - 1
            y = int(move[1]) - 1
            if isValidMove(board, playerTile, x, y) == False:
                continue
            else:
                break
        else:
            print('Это недопустимый ход. Введите номер столбца (1-8) и номер ряда (1-8).')
            print('К примеру, значение 81 перемещает в верхний правый угол.')

    return [x, y]

def getComputerMove(board, computerTile):
    # Учитывая данное игровое поле и данную фишку компьютера, определить,
    # куда сделать ход, и вернуть этот ход в виде списка [x, y]
    possibleMoves = getValidMoves(board, computerTile)
    random.shuffle(possibleMoves) # randomize the order of the moves

    # Всегда делать ход в угол, если это возможно
    for x, y in possibleMoves:
        if isOnCorner(x, y):
            return [x, y]

    # Найти ход с наибольшим возможным количеством очков
    bestScore = -1
    for x, y in possibleMoves:
        boardCopy = getBoardCopy(board)
        makeMove(boardCopy, computerTile, x, y)
        score = getScoreOfBoard(boardCopy)[computerTile]
        if score > bestScore:
            bestMove = [x, y]
            bestScore = score
    return bestMove

def printScore(board, playerTile, computerTile):
    scores = getScoreOfBoard(board)
    print('Ваш счет: %s. Счет компьютера: %s.' % (scores[playerTile], scores[computerTile]))

def playGame(playerTile, computerTile):
    showHints = False
    turn = whoGoesFirst()
    print(turn + ' ходит первым.')

        # Очистить игровое поле и выставить стартовые фишки
    board = getNewBoard()
    board[3][3] = ' X '
    board[3][4] = ' O '
    board[4][3] = ' O '
    board[4][4] = ' X '

    while True:
        playerValidMoves = getValidMoves(board, playerTile)
        computerValidMoves = getValidMoves(board, computerTile)

        if playerValidMoves == [] and computerValidMoves == []:
            return board # Ни у кого нет ходов, так что игра окончена.

        elif turn == 'игрок': # Ход игрока
            if playerValidMoves != []:
                if showHints:
                    validMovesBoard = getBoardWithValidMoves(board, playerTile)
                    drawBoard(validMovesBoard)
                else:
                    drawBoard(board)
                printScore(board, playerTile, computerTile)

                move = getPlayerMove(board, playerTile)
                if move == 'выход':
                    print('Благодарю за игру!')
                    sys.exit() # Завершить работу программы
                elif move == 'подсказка':
                    showHints = not showHints
                    continue
                else:
                    makeMove(board, playerTile, move[0], move[1])
            turn = 'компьютер'

        elif turn == 'компьютер': # Ход компьютера
            if computerValidMoves != []:
                drawBoard(board)
                printScore(board, playerTile, computerTile)

                input('Нажмите Enter, чтобы увидеть ход компьютера')
                move = getComputerMove(board, computerTile)
                makeMove(board, computerTile, move[0], move[1])
            turn = 'игрок'







root = Tk()
root.title(u'Реверси')#Название окна
root.geometry('400x650+300+200') # ширина=500, высота=400, x=300, y=200
root.resizable(False, False)#запретит изменение размеров главного окна как по горизонтали

#Расстановка и конфигурация элементов интерфейса
INPUT_Text = StringVar()
main_text = Text(borderwidth=4,relief="groove",width=100,height=20, bg="#829163")
label_info = Label(borderwidth=4,relief="groove",width=200,text="Hello GGG", bg="#829163")
button_push=Button(command=start,borderwidth=4,relief="raised",text='Enter/Ввод',width=100,height=3,font='arial 14')
Input = Entry( textvariable=INPUT_Text,borderwidth=4,relief="groove",width=100,font = "arial 32 bold")



main_text  .pack(padx=20,pady=20)
label_info.pack(padx=20, pady=20,ipady=10)
button_push.pack(padx=20,pady=20,side='bottom')
Input.pack(side='bottom',padx=20, pady=20,ipady=10)
#

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Нужно либо избавиться от цикла `while` и использовать вместо него цикл событий tkinter, либо на каждой итерации вызывать `root.pdate_idletasks()`.

Answer (score 0):

Народ если кто то делает с Tkinterom программу в которой есть цикл while - чтобы tkinter не зависал это исправлется легко
данный цикл вы засовываете в функцию к примеру называете эту функцию страт и прописываете что эта функция будет запускаться в новом потоке 2 строчки

```
from threading import Thread#Импорт библиотеки
Thread(target=start).start()#Запуск функции страт в новом потоке
```

Comment: Не надо так делать. Tkinter не является потокобезопасным, обращения к компонентам графического интерфейса из потоков могут привести к сбоям.